# Можно ли в Visual Basic делать современный интнрфейс

Tags: winapi, visual-basic

У вас тут написано, что для `Delphi` есть дополнение `ComCtl32.dll v.6`, которое позволяет делать интерфейс с поддержкой интерфейса `Windows XP/Vista/7` (а не квадратные дряхлые кнопки и полосы прокрутки). Можно ли так-же сделать для `Visual Basic 6.0` и где скачать такой мод? Или как [сдесь](http://www.programmon.ru/Delphi7prof/6.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я знаю, есть библиотека только для кнопок, позволяет делать красивые кнопки. http://www.mediafire.com/?g96pss1sle5k3iv , и вот урок http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NPm1jOzmwM

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Пора уже забыть про VB, особенно в версии 6.0, как про страшный сон или про детские увлечения и перейти к работе на более серьезных языках, к тем же дельфам, еще лучше -VS С++/C#.

Comment: А там можно сделать современный интерфейс?Где можно скачать учебник?

Comment: Там можно делать все, что угодно, особенно в VS. Учебников куча. Подобные вопросы здесь уже обсуждались неоднократно. Поищите соответствующие темы.

Comment: В Visual Studio можно делать абсолютно любой интерфейс, при желании и достаточном умении можно делать любой интерфейс.